# How do I demostrate the Galois Group of this particular extension?

Tags: polynomials

I saw this exercise in a old porposed exercise sheet and it frustates me because I suspect it is very easy, yet I'm stuck. Here it is:

Alright so I know that Q({α_n: n ∈ N}) which is by definition the smallest subfield of R which contains Q∪{α_n: n ∈ N}. So even it seem likely for this set to be infinite I struggle to prove it rigurously. I can either see its any of the Q-automorphisms. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can build an infinite tower of extensions by adjoining first $\sqrt2$, then $\sqrt[3]2,~\sqrt[4]2,\dots$ one after the other. Try to show that each of these intermediate extensions has degree greater than $1$. For the automorphisms, keep in mind that $\alpha_n$ must be sent to some root of its minimal polynomial $X^n-2$ (need to prove that it is in fact minimal). Which of those roots are contained in your field?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K:=\mathbb Q(\{\sqrt[n]2\}_{n\ge2})\subseteq\mathbb R$, and let $f\colon K\to K$ be a $\mathbb Q$-automorphism. If $n$ is odd, then $f(\sqrt[n]2)^n=f(2)=2$, so that since $f(\sqrt[n]2)\in\mathbb R$, we have $f(\sqrt[n]2)=\sqrt[n]2$.

Let $n\ge2$ be an even integer such that $f(\sqrt[n]2)\ne \sqrt[n]2$. Again, since $f(\sqrt[n]2)^n=2$, we must have $f(\sqrt[n]2)=-\sqrt[n]2$. However, then $x=f(\sqrt[2n]2)$ is such that $x^2=-\sqrt[n]2$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. This is clearly impossible.

We thus conclude that $f(\sqrt[n]2)=\sqrt[n]2$ for each $n\ge2$, so that $f$ is the identity.

Comment: Every element of $K$ is a rational function of the $\sqrt[n]2$...